# how to check to make sure that each character of the command line argument is a decimal digit (i.e., 0, 1, 2, etc.)

Tags: c, cs50

I'm a little stuck on part of a CS50 encryption exercise where we have to implement a program that encrypts messages using Caesar’s cipher, in language C.

Specifically this part: "Modify caesar.c such that instead of printing out the command-line argument provided, your program instead checks to make sure that each character of that command line argument is a decimal digit (i.e., 0, 1, 2, etc.) and, if any of them are not, terminates after printing the message Usage: ./caesar key."

My code as follows:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    //checks if the user provides exactly one command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("success\n");
    }


    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        // check if any of the characters of the command-line argument is not a decimal digit
        
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("success\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {       
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the first part works (checking for one command line argument), but when I enter a string of decimal digits as that argument, like 123c or 1c23 it still prints success.

Obviously that's because the loop checks if the first char in the string is a digit and if so immediately prints success. Hence I want to find a simple way in my code to check each character of the argument is a digit and only then print success or Usage: ./caesar key.

Thanks for any help, please let me know if more background info of the problem set is needed.

Comment: Just change the logic to be `if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]))` and no need for `else` case.

Comment: You could do: `if ( ! isdigit( argv[1][i] ) ) { 
     printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n"); 
     exit(1);
 }`and remove whole of `else` part.

Comment: @Ahtisham yes, or may be move the else branch after the loop. Did you read the answers ?

Comment: @bruno yes i did, he can also use `if ( isalpha(argv[1][i]) ) `

Comment: @Ahtisham no, there are character not being alpha but also not being digit, I mean isalpha is not the reverse of isdigit

Comment: @bruno can you give an example ?

Comment: @Ahtisham `isalpha(c)` is equivalent to `isupper(c) || islower(c)`, some example of non digit nor alpha : `&,:;.%!)({}\|[]&`

Comment: @JohnForkosh sry I don't get your answer. Can you please give an example how to write it in my code?

Comment: @JohnForkosh proposes you replace all your loop by for instance `puts((strspn(argv[1],"0123456789") == strlen(argv[1])) ? "success" : "Usage: ./caesar key");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

doing

> ```
> for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
> {
>    // check if any of the characters of the command-line argument is not a decimal digit
>    
>    if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
>    {
>        printf("success\n");
>        return 0;
>    }
>    else
>    {       
>        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
>        return 1;
>    }
> }
> ```

you only consider the first character of `argv[1]` because you return in both branch of the `if`

you can do

```
for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
{
    // check if any of the characters of the command-line argument is not a decimal digit
    
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char) argv[1][i]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

printf("success\n");
return 0;
```

but an empty argument is considered accepted and very probably you also want to get the number so rather than to loop as you do you can use `strtol` or `scanf` to both get the number and check you have a number, so for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  //checks if the user provides exactly one command-line argument
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: %s key\n", *argv);
    return 1;
  }
  
  int key;
  char c;
  
  // check argv[1] is only a number
  if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d %c", &key, &c) != 1)
  {
    printf("'%s' is not a valid key\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }
  
  printf("valid key %d\n", key);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Usage: ./a.out key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aze
'aze' is not a valid key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1a
'1a' is not a valid key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out a1
'a1' is not a valid key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1
valid key 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 123
valid key 123
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out "123 "
valid key 123
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out "123 a"
'123 a' is not a valid key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out " 123 "
valid key 123
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out " "
' ' is not a valid key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ""
'' is not a valid key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

as you see spaces are tolerated, this is very usual reading a number

Of course if you do not want negative number do

```
if ((sscanf(argv[1], "%d %c", &key, &c) != 1) || (key < 0))
```

---

[edit for your remark]

> For the first part even when I run if (!isdigit((unsigned char) argv[1][i])) the code still doesn't work correctly. F.e. if I run f.e. ./caesar 12p is still prints success (same problem as before).

that means you did not get all my code and probably continue to have your `if` with the two branches, if I put my first proposal in a full program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  //checks if the user provides exactly one command-line argument
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: %s key\n", *argv);
    return 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
  {
    // check if any of the characters of the command-line argument is not a decimal digit
    
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char) argv[1][i]))
    {
      printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  
  printf("success\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 12p
Usage: ./caesar key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 12
success
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: The string length is only computed once in OP's code, although even once is unnecessary as you've shown.

Comment: @interjay oh yes you are right, I read wrongly the OP code

Comment: @bruno thanks for your answer. For the first part even when I run 
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char) argv[1][i]))  the code still doesn't work correctly. F.e. if I run f.e. ./caesar 12p is still prints success (same problem as before). I'm trying to understand your other solution, some new terms for me.

Comment: @Dimi3 my first proposal works, I edited my answer see its new end

Comment: @bruno my bad I accidentally kept  printf("success\n"); return 0; inside the for loop - thank you very much :-) p.s. what does the unsigned char mean in this case?

Comment: @Dimi3 I force `unsigned char` to not use a `char` being the type of `argv[1][i]` to allow *isdigit* to work whatever the fact a `char`is signed or not including if you forced that throw an option when compiling, this is because the functions isxxx get an `int` and the conversion can be wrong

Comment: @bruno cool I've ticked your answer as correct, the code works fine now. Noted for the  unsigned char. This was my first post on SO and super delighted with the feedback - cheers!